# Google Optimize custom activation event tracking across multiple pages

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, ab-testing, google-optimize

I am implementing an A/B test with Google Optimize, using a custom activation event. I render different versions of the same React component based on which ID variant I receive from Optimize.

```
            const getVariant = async () => {
                if (window.dataLayer) {
                    await window.dataLayer.push({ event: 'optimize.activate' });
                }
                const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                    if (window.google_optimize !== undefined) {
                        const variant = window.google_optimize.get(myExperimentId);
                        setUseTestVariant(Number(variant));
                        clearInterval(intervalId);
                        console.log(variant)
                    }
                }, 100);
            };
```

So far this works for randomly generating a different version of the same component corresponding to a variant in my Optimize experiment. But the main objective of the test is to track conversation rate through purchases on the checkout page, where the component which fires the event is not located. So my question is: if the custom activation event is triggered on one page and a session is started, does Optimize know when the user clicks through to the checkout page, or would that page also require an activation event to be pushed to the datalayer? Is it only possible to track interactions on the page that the event was fired from?

Answer (score 0):

Optimize set the _gaexp cookie in your browser, in this cookie stores the experiment variant. This value is stored in google analytics as session scope, therfore, all custom events and transactions in this session will be attached with this variant. You don't need to activate the experiment in another page to save the transaction with the variant.

On the other hand, I don´t know your experiment, but it is usually not a good idea to set Transactions as primary objective. Transactions, in general, are secundary objetives. As primary objetive it is better to use the click in the component that you has changed, for example... add to cart, but depends of the experiment of course